# Static resource won't refresh

Tags: javascript, static-resources, cache

I have a static resource with is a Javascript file of about 1mb. 
After successfully uploading the file, and clearing the cache of the page that uses the static resource, it's still using the old javascript file. 
Tried it 5+ times, still doesn't work.

Anybody know why it might be the case?

I'm workin in: 
https://c.na30.visual.force.com

Comment: Please post the Visualforce code that pulls in the JS file.

Comment: Are you using `{!URLFOR(...)}` or hard-coding your own URL?

Comment: Well, miraculously, it started working that afternoon. No idea why. 

Just feel like I need to up date you on this. Thanks all!